# Moving Directories

Tags: batch-file, move

I have created a txt file with a list of directories I need to move to a new location. However there is a large number of directories, and trying to copy and paste just some will take forever.

How can I use this txt file to move only those directories to a new folder? I want to also keep each directories sub-directories in tact.

Thanks.

Comment: By writing code that reads the text file and moves the listed directories... Or do you also have a *specific programming question*??

Comment: I'm not sure what the could would be :-(, so I am hoping for some assistance with the code.

Comment: Asking for code is off-topic here, as StackOverflow is not a free code writing service! Hence you need to try it on your own and when stuck, come back here, ask a specific question, including your code and a detailed description what it is supposed to do and what it actually does. A good starting point is [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) and [`move`](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /b/ad "%sourcedir%\t w o" ') DO MOVE "%sourcedir%\t w o\%%a" "%destdir%\%%a"

GOTO :EOF
```

This is an example of how I would do it. The `dir` command produces a directory list of the subdirectories of `"%sourcedir%\t w o"` which is simply a test directory. The `delims=` ensures the entire directory name from the list is applied to `%%a`.

If your list in `afile.txt` is something like

```
u:\somedirectory to move
u:\someotherdirectory to move
u:\moveme
```

then

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (afile.txt) DO ECHO(MOVE "%%a" "%destdir%\%%~nxa"
```

should list the proposed moves. Remove the `echo(` to actually do the move (after checking...)